# How to create username and password for the docker installed in remote machine?

Tags: linux, docker

I have installed docker in remote Linux machine and my aim is to push images from local to remote docker and in order to gain access to remote Linux machine I need credentials.

So, my question is how to set up authentication for docker in remote Linux machine and hence I can docker login from a local machine to remote docker installed Linux machine

Comment: Do you have a docker registry on the remote machine? Or do you need a user who can manage the docker instance?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I am a complete newbie to container env and docker is installed on the remote machine but i am not sure i understand the difference b/w docker and registry.